# Give an example of two sets A and B such that |A| = |B|, and a function f : A → B such that f is one-to-one but not onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Actually, I am a new student in discrete mathematics and this question appeared in my text book. And just before that I read that if |A|=|B| then the function must be one-one, onto, Invertible if any one of these is correct for the given functions but now they are saying opposite of this. Can you please explain me this by giving the example?

I am reposting this question for the clarification that is function, f(x) =x+5 on natural number is correct answer? If you wanna check the conversation about this question then you can check the exact question posted approximately 50 minutes ago... Actually in that question we messed up in comment section and lost the talk.
Thanks

Comment: The theorem doesn't say if $|A|=|B|$ then the functions $A$ and $B$ must be one-one, onto, invertible. That wouldn't make sense since $A$ and $B$ are sets, not functions.

Comment: sorry, these are sets. Right!

Comment: $|A|=|B|$ means that *some* function between them must exists that is ... all the stuff you say.  But that doesn't mean *all* functions between them must be that. if $f(x) = x+5$ then $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ (because $f(n)=n+5\in \mathbb N$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. and $f$ is 1-1 (because $f(n)=f(m)\implies n+5 = m+5\implies n=m$. but $f$ is not onto because $f(n)= 1,2,3,4,5$ do not have any solution.

Comment: "I read that if |A|=|B| then the function must be"..... so by the socratic method I feel obligated to ask "when you say *the* function, which function do you mean?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ givem by $f(x)=x+5$ is indeed one-one but not onto. One-one: assume $f(x)=f(y),$ then $x+5=y+5,$ then $x=y$ since we may subtract $5$ from both sides. Also $f$ is not onto since $f(x)=1$ has no solution.

Edit: technically "subtract $5$ from each side" isn't quite valid. What if one side were $5,$ then subtracting $5$ gives $0$ which is not in $\mathbb{N}.$ But an easy inductive argument takes care of that gap in logic.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x+5$, from the natural numbers to itself, is indeed an example of the type asked in the question.

It is true that if $|A|=|B|$ *and $A$ and $B$ are finite sets*, then a function $f\colon A\to B$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto if and only if it is invertible. However, this theorem holds only for finite sets, as your example shows.

Moral of the story (and a step in the learning process for most people learning foundations of mathematics): when reading theorems, it's important to internalize not just the conclusions of the theorem but the *hypotheses* of the theorem as well.